# get property from set lombok value

Tags: collections, lombok

Hi I have been trying to figure out how to get `stateCode` from a `Places` object by using stream.  I am using lombok to parse the json object which looks like this:

```
{"post code": "90210", "country": "United States", "country abbreviation": "US", "places": [{"place name": "Beverly Hills", "longitude": "-118.4065", "state": "California", "state abbreviation": "CA", "latitude": "34.0901"}]}
```

I've constructed a class to process the object like so:

```
@lombok.Value
public class ZipCode {
  @JsonAlias("post code")
  private final String postalCode;
  private final  Set<Places> places;

  public ZipCode() {
    this.postalCode = null;
    this.places = null;
  }

  public ZipCode(String postalCode, Set<Places> places) {
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
    this.places = places;
  }

  @lombok.Value
  private static class Places {
    @JsonAlias("state abbreviation")
    private  final String stateCode;
  }
}
```

I thought that if I used

```
ZipCode zip = getZipObject();
String stateCode = zip.getPlaces().stream().findFirst().toString();
```

I would be able to get the `stateCode` as a string. In my example the `stateCode` should've been  "CA". Instead I get `Optional[ZipCode.Places(stateCode=NY)]`. If anyone could help me with this I would appreciate it. I am keeping the ZipCode class in a separate class. I would like to keep it that way. Most of the examples that I've. seen with using `stream` tend to use the set object itself. I want to avoid having to make my `Places` object publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the stateCode property by modifying the ZipCode class like so

```
@lombok.Value
public class ZipCode {
  @JsonAlias("post code")
  private final String postalCode;
  private final  Set<Places> places;

  @lombok.Value
  public static class Places {
    @JsonAlias("state abbreviation")
    private  final String stateCode;
  }
}
```

Then I used stream like so

```
if(zip.getPlaces().stream().findFirst().isPresent())
     String state = zip.getPlaces().stream().findFirst().get().getStateCode();
```

This produce an output of "CA" for the example json.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: You should always check `isPresent()` of an `Optional` before calling `get()`.

Comment: Nice catch, I will add that and wrap it an exception. I'm updating my answer now.